# Enigma: Theorie Rotors

Tags: enigma

I wanted to programm the enigma (using C#). But it seems like i dont understand how the rotors work. Becouse if we take the first three rotors:

1. ekmflgdqvzntowyhxuspaibrcj
2. ajdksiruxblhwtmcqgznpyfvoe
3. bdfhjlcprtxvznyeiwgakmusqo
   UKW A: ae  bj  cm  dz  fl  gy  hx  iv  kw  nr  oq  pu  st
   (The meaning of the possitions are from a-z oc).

So if we take the route of A now: a-e; e-s; s-g; g-y; y-q; q-q; q-x; x= encrypted output.

Now lets go back again: x-r; r-g; g-c; c-m; m-z; z-e; e-l; l = decrypted output

So where is my logical problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the signal goes back through the rotors after the reflector, the permutation for each rotor is [inverted](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24877/why-is-this-the-inverse-of-a-enigma-machine-rotor). That's what you're missing.

In a way, this is kind of obvious: if going through the rotor one way would map, say, A to E, then going through it the other way has to map E to A, and so on.

(The permutation applied by the reflector itself is always, by design, its own inverse; it just swaps distinct pairs of letters.)

Comment: Hmm but if i go back than x-k; k-d; d-g which is again wrong or am i missing still smth?

Comment: okay nevermind its correct ty